# How do I make my bot list all bots found in my server?

Tags: javascript, arrays, bots, discord, discord.js

As stated in the title I'd like to make a script that allows me to get a list of the bots in a specific server. check the screenshot below 
[image: SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 0):

It should work similarly to this:

```
    message.guild.members.fetch().then((members)=>{
        for (let m of members.entries()) {
            let mContent = m[1] // get value of member key:value pair

            if (mContent.user.bot) {
                console.log(mContent.user)
            }
        }
    })
```

This assumes that the script is running within an 'on message' event handler, so you have access to the message object. However, you can use the Discord client object to get all guilds and then loop through each guild, performing this script.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply.
I am looking to have one that puts all the bots in an embed, and send them back, as provided in the screenshot. thanks

Comment: So I would reference this link to learn more about embeds: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview

 
Then, you can use the code I placed above to get all of the bots in the guild, add them to an object and then display them within the addFields method in the embed